# Adjusting navigation bar to fit screen width

Tags: html, css, nav

I'd like to increase the width of the border below my top social buttons, navigation menu and footer social widgets to fit the width of the screen but can't seem to figure out how to.

My page - [www.adelinesays.blogspot.com](http://adelinesays.blogspot.com)

Comment: Just keep your `div` with the **id** of `top-social` outside of your `outerwrapper div` in your html and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have `#top-social` nested as a child of `.outerwrapper`.

If you remove the property `width: 1100px;` from .outerwrapper it will extend the #top-social component the full width.

Basically `.outerwrapper` is making `#top-social` have a maximum block width of 1100px.

If you open up Chrome developer tools (command + option + "i") on Mac, you will be able to select the `.outerwrapper` and uncheck `width: 1100px;` and you will see the desired output that you are looking for.

I think this is the simplest solution and I see it working as desired just with this one change.

If you find problems elsewhere by removing this max-width, you can create another container on the same top level as `.outerwrapper` and just put your top navigation items inside of it. The fact that you are nesting a "full-width" top navigation inside of a constrained width parent component (a component higher up in the vertical rythm to the nested `#top-social` component) means that the #top-social component is inheriting this max-width from its parent `.outerwrapper`.

Hope this helps!
@javascriptjames
http://jamescoury.com

Answer (score 0):

The way your website is built, you could delete outerwrapper altogether and apply container class to those elements that you wish to maintain width of 1100px.

Deleting outerwrapper div, container div surrounding navigation and adding container class to widget-content div would achieve the layout you wish in this case.